# Java. Runtime compile method with different types and numbers of parameters

Tags: java, compilation, runtime

I create web application where user can input Java source code in input area, then send it to server, compile it in runtime and test it. But I don't know, how create file for compilation and how keep signature of methods (sequence and types of parameters).

**For example, I have method such as:**

```
public Integer sum(Integer first, Integer second){
    return first + second;
}
```

But how I can keep this signature of method in database and create file which should be compile? 
Now I am creating method which get a testing input value (in this case: 1, 5 [Integer, Integer]) and then create Scanner of input and read values such as scanner.nextInt(), add it in List of object etc and in the end run method such as sum((Integer)list.get(0), (Integer)list.get(1)).

**That if other types of data and a different number of input parameters of the method?**

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(input);
List list = new ArrayList();
while(sc.hasNextInt()){
    Integer value = scanner.nextInt();
    list.add(value);
}
int sumResult = sum((Integer)list.get(0), (Integer)list.get(1));
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: This is dangerous to do unless you have a very good idea of all the security implications. If I can run code on your server I can get it to do anything.  Saving the input to a file, compiling it and run it is trivial by comparison.

Comment: Yes, @PeterLawrey, I know. But I think that maybe to do something for protecting from rm -rf etc.

Comment: If I can do what I want on your server, I won't be deleting it ;)

Comment: Yes,but  I don't make better idea than it. And the question is about different types and numbers of parameters))

Comment: You'd be amazed at how sneaky/malicious people can be. If this is just a homework problem, or just for you, that's another story. If you are opening this to the internet at large, be careful. rm -rf is not the only thing to look out for ;)

Comment: First of all it`s project for me, but after maybe deploy in the Internet.